# How can I execute multiple SQL statements in Python script?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I am working with the following code template in Python (using Atom to build/write).

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client


cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL 
Server}',server ='prodserver', database = 'XXXX')

cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setencoding(str, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setencoding(unicode, encoding='utf-8', ctype=pyodbc.SQL_CHAR)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
script ="""SELECT AccountsCount.AccountClass, COUNT(*) as Count
   FROM
        (SELECT *
        FROM XXXX.dbo.table
        where SubNo='001'
        AND (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' AND
   convert(date,AddDate) = DATEADD(DAY, -2, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
  ) OR
  (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 'Monday' AND
   convert(date,AddDate) = DATEADD(DAY, -3, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
  ) OR
  (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' AND
   convert(date,AddDate) = DATEADD(DAY, -2, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
  ) OR
  (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) NOT IN ('Sunday', 'Monday') AND
   convert(date,AddDate) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
  )) AS AccountsCount
  Group by AccountsCount.AccountClass
  """

df = pd.read_sql_query(script,cnxn)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter ('ExcelFile.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Data Export')
writer.save()

xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
xlsPath = ('OtherExcelFile.xlsm')
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath)
xlApp.Run('CopyIntoOutlook')
wb.Save()
xlApp.Quit()
```

All I need to do is add a second and completely separate SQL command to this script which runs absolutely flawlessly and does what I need it to do as is above.  My additional script is something like this

```
script= """ select AccountClass, COUNT(*) as Count
    FROM XXXX.dbo.table
    where SubNo='001'
    AND AddDate >= '1/1/2017'
  Group by AccountClass """
```

I have had no luck with anything I've tried as far as adding into the script, any help is greatly apprecaited!  You'll notice the second script is using the same DB and table as the original, I just need YTD data as well as the top query which is looking at one day previous.

Comment: What problem are you having? Just execute the second query with `pd.read_sql_query()`

Comment: Why do you have this tagged `mysql` when you're clearly using SQL-Server?

Comment: What is your desired output? That second query as a new Excel worksheet? Run same process but change `SELECT` statement and destination worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

update:

I was able to figure this out, wrote in the following under write.save()

```
script2= """
select AccountClass, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM XXXX.dbo.table
where SubNo='001'
AND AddDate >= '1/1/2017'
Group by AccountClass 
"""

df2 = pd.read_sql_query(script2,cnxn)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter ('ExcelFile.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Data Export')
writer.save()
```